# Deferred renderer with stencil buffer FBO

Tags: c++, opengl

In my deferred renderer I create a FBO for my geometry pass where I store also a depth + stencil buffer into a texture with these parameters:

- Attachment: `GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT`
- Format: `GL_DEPTH_STENCIL`
- Internal format: `GL_DEPTH32F_STENCIL8`
- Data type: `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8`

and I can successfully populate this texture with depth and stencil.

The problem I'm facing now is how to use the stencil buffer created in my geometry pass in order to use it somewhere else, like when I do a directional light pass I'd like to process only the pixels covered by the geometry visible on my geometry pass.

So, how can I use the stencil buffer stored during my geometry pass for further use?

Comment: The stencil test is like the depth test, while rendering you are reading and writing from the same buffer. So if you want to use your stencil buffer in a later rendering pass you need to attach or blit it to the currently bound framebuffer.

Comment: Ok but I use the depth buffer as a texture sampler in my shaders. I've never tried to use it as the actual buffer in order to do depth tests and so I don't even know how to use the previously created stencil to do stencil test. So how can I use them? I've read that blitting doesn't always work.

Comment: One thing to note is that directional lights should probably affect your whole scene and thus not require a stencil test in order to cull pixels. That part is mostly for light volumes and other bounded light sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can of course always use the stencil buffer for stencil testing. To illustrate how to use stencil testing on a basic level, here are the critical calls for an example where you draw in two passes, where in the second pass we will exclude all pixels that were not covered in the first pass:

- When you clear the framebuffer, make sure that you include the bit for clearing the stencil buffer:

  ```
  glClear(... | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
  ```
- Enable the stencil test:

  ```
  glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
  ```
- Set up the stencil function/operation to set the value in the stencil buffer to 1 for all rendered pixels:

  ```
  glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, 1);
  glStencilOp(GL_REPLACE, GL_REPLACE, GL_REPLACE);
  ```

  `GL_ALWAYS` specifies that all pixels pass the stencil test (i.e. no pixels are rejected). `GL_REPLACE` specifies that the value in the stencil buffer is replaced by the reference value, which is the second argument to `glStencilFunc()`, for all rendered pixels.
- Draw the geometry for the first pass.
- Change the stencil function/operation to only render pixels where the value in the stencil buffer is 1:

  ```
  glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 1, 1);
  glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP);
  ```

  `GL_EQUAL` specifies that only pixels at positions where the stencil buffer value is equal to the reference value 1 pass the stencil test, and all other pixels are rejected. `GL_KEEP` specifies that the current values in the stencil buffer are not modified in this pass.
- Draw the geometry for the second pass.

But the way I read your question, you're looking for something different. You want to sample the stencil buffer from one rendering pass in a later rendering pass, similar to the way you can sample depth textures.

This is supported in OpenGL 4.3 and later. With `texId` the name of your depth/stencil texture, the key part is this texture parameter setting:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
glTexParamteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_TEXTURE_MODE, GL_STENCIL_INDEX);
```

This specifies that the stencil part of the depth/stencil texture should be used for sampling. Only nearest sampling is supported for stencil textures, so make sure that you also have these values:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

Not surprisingly based on the nature of the value, stencil textures are treated as unsigned integer textures. This means that the sampler type in the shader code needs to be `usampler2D`:

```
uniform usampler2D MyStencilTexture;
```

And when you sample the texture, the result will also be of type unsigned:

```
uvec4 stencilValue = texture(MyStencilTexture, textureCoordinates);
```

The stencil value will then be in `stencilValue.r`.

Comment: Ok, really interesting and I'm thinking to use this method for some thing I'm gonna do. But what I'm looking for is something different I think. At the moment I don't need to sample the stencil buffer in my shaders like I do for the depth buffer, I just need to use it to draw only a portion of my viewport, excluding the rest in order to try to optimize some drawing. For example when I do my directional light pass, I don't need to draw the entire viewport quad, but only the section where the is some geometry, so I was planning to use a stencil buffer created during my first geometry pass.

Comment: @zeb I added some explanation for basic stencil buffer usage.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm going to try like that now.

Comment: just perfect. I was able to use the stencil test like I was planning to.
My rendering pipeline looks like this now:
[first] **geometry pass fills the FBO so also the stencil buffer like you showed me**
[second] **directional light pass blits the stencil buffer from the geometry pass into the light buffer and uses the stencil buffer like you told me.**

I used the same method to implement the skybox. Wonderful! Thanks a lot!